# Issues while Cuda SDK Sample in ubuntu

Tags: compilation, cuda, installation, ubuntu-11.04

I am using ubuntu 11.04 and cuda 4.2. I installed the Toolkit and the SDK. I used https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cuda website for installation.
After that, I am giving the make commands to the sample problems given in GPU SDK using the following commands

cd ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C
LINKFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/nvidia-current/ make cuda-install=/opt/cuda

But while doing that I am receiving tons of warnings and errors. From the type of error messages what it seems that the error message starts occuring after the particle example starts compiling. I will paste the error messages below :

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/duttasankha/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/src/particles'
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot open //usr/lib/libGL.so: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function reshape(int, int):particles.cpp(.text+0x160): error: undefined reference to 'glMatrixMode'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function reshape(int, int):particles.cpp(.text+0x165): error: undefined reference to 'glLoadIdentity'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function reshape(int, int):particles.cpp(.text+0x19e): error: undefined reference to 'glMatrixMode'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function reshape(int, int):particles.cpp(.text+0x1ab): error: undefined reference to 'glViewport'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function initGL(int*, char**):particles.cpp(.text+0x399): error: undefined reference to 'glEnable'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function initGL(int*, char**):particles.cpp(.text+0x3b4): error: undefined reference to 'glClearColor'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x8a5): error: undefined reference to 'glClear'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x8af): error: undefined reference to 'glMatrixMode'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x8b4): error: undefined reference to 'glLoadIdentity'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x92f): error: undefined reference to 'glTranslatef'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x948): error: undefined reference to 'glRotatef'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x961): error: undefined reference to 'glRotatef'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x972): error: undefined reference to 'glGetFloatv'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x985): error: undefined reference to 'glColor3f'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x997): error: undefined reference to 'glPushMatrix'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x9b8): error: undefined reference to 'glTranslatef'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x8
6_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x9cb): error: undefined reference to 'glColor3f'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0x9ee): error: undefined reference to 'glPopMatrix'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0xb06): error: undefined reference to 'glDisable'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0xb12): error: undefined reference to 'glBlendFunc'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0xb1c): error: undefined reference to 'glEnable'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0xb3b): error: undefined reference to 'glDisable'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/particles.cpp.o: in function display():particles.cpp(.text+0xb45): error: undefined reference to 'glEnable'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::_
drawPoints():render_particles.cpp(.text+0x41): error: undefined reference to 'glBegin'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::_drawPoints():render_particles.cpp(.text+0x66): error: undefined reference to 'glVertex3fv'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::_drawPoints():render_particles.cpp(.text+0x9e): error: undefined reference to 'glVertexPointer'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::_drawPoints():render_particles.cpp(.text+0xa8): error: undefined reference to 'glEnableClientState'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::_drawPoints():render_particles.cpp(.text+0xbb): error: undefined reference to 'glDrawArrays'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::_drawPoints():render_particles.cpp(.text+0xcf): error: undefined reference to 'glDisableClientState'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::_drawPoints():render_particles.cpp(.text+0xff): error: undefined reference to 'glColorPointer'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::_drawPoints():render_particles.cpp(.text+0x109): error: undefined reference to 'glEnableClientState'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::display(ParticleRenderer::DisplayMode):render_particles.cpp(.text+0x143): error: undefined reference to 'glColor3f'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::display(ParticleRenderer::DisplayMode):render_particles.cpp(.text+0x14d): error: undefined reference to 'glPointSize'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::display(ParticleRenderer::DisplayMode):render_particles.cpp(.text+0x186): error: undefined reference to 'glEnable'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::display(ParticleRenderer::DisplayMode):render_particles.cpp(.text+0x19a): error: undefined reference to 'glTexEnvi'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::display(ParticleRenderer::DisplayMode):render_particles.cpp(.text+0x1ae): error: undefined reference to 'glDepthMask'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::display(ParticleRenderer::DisplayMode):render_particles.cpp(.text+0x25b): error: undefined reference to 'glColor3f'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::_drawPoints():render_particles.cpp(.text+0x74): error: undefined reference to 'glEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::_drawPoints():render_particles.cpp(.text+0xdd): error: undefined reference to 'glDisableClientState'
/usr/bin/ld: obj/x86_64/release/render_particles.cpp.o: in function ParticleRenderer::display(ParticleRenderer::DisplayMode):render_particles.cpp(.text+0x28f): error: undefined reference to 'glDisable'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../common/lib/linux/libGLEW_x86_64.a(glew.o): in function glewGetExtension:glew.c(.text+0x39e9): error: undefined reference to 'glGetString'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../common/lib/linux/libGLEW_x86_64.a(glew.o): in function _glewInit_GL_EXT_texture_perturb_normal:glew.c(.text+0x3a6a): error: undefined reference to 'glXGetProcAddressARB'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../common/lib/linux/libGLEW_x86_64.a(glew.o): in function _glewInit_GL_EXT_texture_object:glew.c(.text+0x3aa3): error: undefined reference to 'glXGetProcAddressARB'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../common/lib/linux/libGLEW_x86_64.a(glew.o): in function _glewInit_GL_EXT_texture_object:glew.c(.text+0x3ab7): error: undefined reference to 'glXGetProcAddressARB'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../common/lib/linux/libGLEW_x86_64.a(glew.o): in function _glewInit_GL_EXT_texture_object:glew.c(.text+0x3ad9): error: undefined reference to 'glXGetProcAddressARB'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../common/lib/linux/libGLEW_x86_64.a(glew.o): in function glewContextInit:glew.c(.text+0x967b): error: undefined reference to 'glGetString'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../common/lib/linux/libGLEW_x86_64.a(glew.o): in function glxewGetExtension:glew.c(.text+0xe62a): error: undefined reference to 'glXGetClientString'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../common/lib/linux/libGLEW_x86_64.a(glew.o): in function glxewContextInit:glew.c(.text+0xe701): error: undefined reference to 'glXQueryVersion'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function beginWinCoords():paramgl.cpp(.text+0xb): error: undefined reference to 'glMatrixMode'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function beginWinCoords():paramgl.cpp(.text+0x10): error: undefined reference to 'glPushMatrix'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function beginWinCoords():paramgl.cpp(.text+0x15): error: undefined reference to 'glLoadIdentity'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function beginWinCoords():paramgl.cpp(.text+0x47): error: undefined reference to 'glTranslatef'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function beginWinCoords():paramgl.cpp(.text+0x5f): error: undefined reference to 'glScalef'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function beginWinCoords():paramgl.cpp(.text+0x6e): error: undefined reference to 'glPushMatrix'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../
lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function beginWinCoords():paramgl.cpp(.text+0x73): error: undefined reference to 'glLoadIdentity'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function beginWinCoords():paramgl.cpp(.text+0xab): error: undefined reference to 'glOrtho'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function endWinCoords():paramgl.cpp(.text+0xcf): error: undefined reference to 'glPopMatrix'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function glPrint(int, int, char const*, void*):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x109): error: undefined reference to 'glRasterPos2f'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function glPrintShadowed(int, int, char const*, void*, float*):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x19d): error: undefined reference to 'glColor3fv'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function ParamListGL::Render(int, int, bool):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x37a): error: undefined reference to 'glColor3fv'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function ParamListGL::Render
(int, int, bool):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x41a): error: undefined reference to 'glColor3fv'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function ParamListGL::Render(int, int, bool):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x424): error: undefined reference to 'glBegin'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function ParamListGL::Render(int, int, bool):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x440): error: undefined reference to 'glVertex2f'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function ParamListGL::Render(int, int, bool):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x45f): error: undefined reference to 'glVertex2f'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function ParamListGL::Render(int, int, bool):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x481): error: undefined reference to 'glVertex2f'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function ParamListGL::Render(int, int, bool):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x4a0): error: undefined reference to 'glVertex2f'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function ParamListGL::Render(int, int, bool):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x4a5): error: undefined reference to 'glEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function ParamListGL::Render(int, int, bool):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x4b1): error: undefined reference to 'glColor3fv'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function ParamListGL::Render(int, int, bool):paramgl.cpp(.text+0x527): error: undefined reference to 'glRectf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libparamgl_x86_64.a(paramgl.cpp.o): in function endWinCoords():paramgl.cpp(.text+0xe2): error: undefined reference to 'glPopMatrix'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CheckFBO::readback(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x143): error: undefined reference to 'glReadBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../
lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CheckFBO::readback(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x18d): error: undefined reference to 'glReadPixels'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CheckFBO::readback(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x20c): error: undefined reference to 'glReadPixels'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CheckFBO::readback(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x31c): error: undefined reference to 'glReadBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CheckBackBuffer::readback(unsigned int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x3b4): error: undefined reference to 'glReadPixels'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CheckBackBuffer::readback(unsigned int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x446): error: undefined reference to 'glReadBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CheckBackBuffer::readback(unsigned int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x471): error: undefined reference to 'glReadPixels'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CheckFBO::readback(unsigned int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x671): error: undefined reference to 'glReadBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::renderQuad(int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xaa5): error: undefined reference to 'glBindTexture'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::renderQuad(int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xabc): error: undefined reference to 'glBindTexture'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::renderQuad(int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xad2): error: undefined reference to 'glClearColor'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::renderQuad(int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xadc): error: undefined reference to 'glClear'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::renderQuad(int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xb01): error: undefined reference to 'glDisable'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::renderQuad(int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xb0b): error: undefined reference to 'glBegin'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::renderQuad(int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xb21): error: undefined reference to 'glTexCoord2f'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::renderQuad(int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xb3d): error: undefined reference to 'glTexCoord2f'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::renderQuad(int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xb5f): error: undefined reference to 'glTexCoord2f'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::renderQuad(int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xb7b): error: undefined reference to 'glTexCoord2f'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::renderQuad(int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xb80): error: undefined reference to 'glEnd'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::freeResources():rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xbeb): error: undefined reference to 'glDeleteTextures'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(renderchttps://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cudaheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::freeResources():rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0xc2a): error: undefined reference to 'glDeleteTextures'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CheckBackBuffer::checkStatus(char const*, int, bool):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x116c): error: undefined reference to 'glGetError'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::createTexture(unsigned int, int, int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x2a16): error: undefined reference to 'glGenTextures'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::createTexture(unsigned int, int, int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x2a21): error: undefined reference to 'glBindTexture'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::createTexture(unsigned int, int, int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x2a32): error: undefined reference to 'glTexParameteri'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::createTexture(unsigned int, int, int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x2a43): error: undefined reference to 'glTexParameteri'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::createTexture(unsigned int, int, int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x2a54): error: undefined reference to 'glTexParameteri'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::createTexture(unsigned int, int, int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x2a65): error: undefined reference to 'glTexParameteri'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::createTexture(unsigned int, int, int, int, unsigned int):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x2a8e): error: undefined reference to 'glTexImage2D'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x30bd): error: undefined reference to 'glGenTextures'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x30c8): error: undefined reference to 'glBindTexture'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x3102): error: undefined reference to 'glTexImage2D'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x3123): error: undefined reference to 'glTexParameterf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x3138): error: undefined reference to 'glTexParameterf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x314d): error: undefined reference to 'glTexParameterf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x3162): error: undefined reference to 'glTexParameterf'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x31f3): error: undefined reference to 'glGetIntegerv'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x320f): error: undefined reference to 'glGetIntegerv'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x32ad): error: undefined reference to 'glGetIntegerv'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/limake[2]: Entering directory `/home/duttasankha/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/src/particles'brendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x32d2): error: undefined reference to 'glGenTextures'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::create(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x3356): error: undefined reference to 'glTexImage2D'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/librendercheckgl_x86_64.a(rendercheck_gl.cpp.o): in function CFrameBufferObject::initialize(unsigned int, unsigned int, fboConfig&, fboData&):rendercheck_gl.cpp(.text+0x3747): error: undefined reference to 'glGetIntegerv'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../bin/linux/release/particles] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/duttasankha/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/src/particles'
make[1]: *** [src/particles/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/duttasankha/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you ever installed the opengl libraries?

Comment: The installation procedure link that I have posted asked to install the freeglut packages and I did it using
sudo apt-get install libxi-dev libxmu-dev freeglut3-dev build-essential binutils-gold

Comment: Test it: sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev

Comment: I copy-pasted it and it is showing:

libgl1-mesa-glx is already the newest version.

libglu1-mesa is already the newest version.

libglu1-mesa-dev is already the newest version.

libglu1-mesa-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Can you write what the following gives you?: locate liGL.so

Comment: I copy pasted locate liGL.so and it returned nothing. What it should return by the way?

Comment: I should also mention that I am using NVidia Geforce 560ti if it is of any relevance

Comment: To install /usr/lib/LibGL.so you can run: sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev... This is my output: /usr/lib/libGL.so
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/libGL.so.304.33
/usr/lib32/libGL.so
/usr/lib32/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/libGL.so.304.33
...

Comment: Actually I didn't get it. I already entered the command which is same as your 3rd comment or is it a different command? if it is different then please give me the full command that I should enter the terminal

Comment: libgl1-mesa-glx and  libgl1-mesa-dev are differents. You have to install the second one for obtaining ligl.so Then make sure it's correctly installed executing: locate libGL.so

Comment: I entered the command sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev.And then I entered locate liGL.so and it returned same as yours. I am copy pasting it below
/home/duttasankha/libGL.so
/usr/lib/libGL.so
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/libGL.so.295.41
/usr/lib/mesa/libGL.so
/usr/lib32/libGL.so
/usr/lib32/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/libGL.so.295.41
/usr/lib32/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/mesa/libGL.so.1.2

Comment: So, Now you can compile?

Comment: I compiled it but still it is giving errors. The same errors.

Comment: Try with: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.295.41 /usr/lib/libGL.so

Comment: I copy pasted the above command and it is returning 
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/lib/libGL.so': File exists

Comment: Sorry, 1- sudo rm /usr/lib/libGL.so then sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.295.41 /usr/lib/libGL.so

Comment: U R JUST AWESOME.THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH.Everything compiled perfectly and all the examples are working fine. While compiling there were some warnings but the examples are running fine. So thanks a ton.

Comment: does my answer solve it? can you run the examples correctly? If it solved your problem, please accept the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: Interesting, that this is closed as off topic. Is SO only about kittehns or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution:

1-Check if libgl is already installed.

```
locate libGL.so
```

It shows something like this:

```
facu@nvd:~$ locate libGL.so
/usr/lib/libGL.so
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/libGL.so.304.33
/usr/lib32/libGL.so
/usr/lib32/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib32/libGL.so.304.33
```

2- If libgl is installed go to 3, if it isn't:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

3- If you can't compile correctly, you have a link broken. Fix it:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/libGL.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.304.33 /usr/lib/libGL.so
```

**Remember to check the version, in my case is 304.33.**

Comment: Installing mesa is the wrong thing to do. This is a CUDA application which requires CUDA-OpenGL interop and it must be built with NVIDIA's OpenGL libraries. The code will still fail to link or run if you try compiling it against mesa.

Comment: @talonmies Please put a the solution, I didn't know it.